# SQLAlchemy 2.0 - Error when using "stringified" forward reference to models in separate files

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to put each of my SQLAlchemy models in a separate file, in a "models" package.  Because of circular reference problems, I am trying to use the "stringified" forward reference trick.

Here's the code in the "models" package:

```py
# __init__.py
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass
```

```py
# parent.py
from typing import List
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, relationship
from app.models import Base


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, index=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
    children: Mapped[List['Child']] = relationship(
        back_populates='parent',viewonly=True)
```

```py
# child.py
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, relationship

from app.models import Base


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, index=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
    parent_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent: Mapped['Parent'] = relationship(
        back_populates='children',
        viewonly=True)
```

And here's the test code:

```py
# test_sa.py
from sqlalchemy import select
from app.models.child import Child


class TestParentChild:

    def test_by_user(self):
        sql = (select(Child, Child.parent)
            .join(Child.parent)
            .limit(10))
        print()
        print(sql)
```

But this gives me the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper
> Mapper[Child(child)], expression 'Parent' failed to locate a name
> ('Parent'). If this is a class name, consider adding this
> relationship() to the <class 'app.models.child.Child'> class after
> both dependent classes have been defined.

This seems like it should be a textbook approach.  Why is SQLAlchemy not finding the `Parent` class while mapping, and how might I fix it?